# Target element via hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a URL:

```
example.com/articles/200#related
```

On my page I have a link that goes to the above URL.

Using jquery, how can I target the link on the page from the URL?

I've tried:

```
$('a[href='+window.location.hash+']');
```

Comment: And the href is exactly `#related`

Comment: The end of the href on the element that Im trying to select is #related

Comment: Well, you're matching **exactly**, meaning the element ***has*** to look like `<a href="#related"></a>`. If you wan't to match just the end, use `$('a[href$='+window.location.hash+']');`